# Web App Central AAA

Tags: authentication, ldap, cas, user-management, aaa-security-protocol

I would like to centralise user management including authentication, authorisation and auditing as this is currently being performed by each application. I was wondering if there is an open source solution already available? I'm aware I can use LDAP or AD but this still requires development of an application to manage users.

I believe LDAP is not an appropriate solution as we require custom user attributes to be defined at runtime which is something LDAP does not support.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is Apereo CAS. It handles what you are after.

See www.github.com/apereo/cas